# meteorjs persistent setUserId to switch user

Tags: javascript, meteor

i'm trying to use meteor this.setUserId()  server side and Meteor.connection.setUserId() client side . It is to let admin have control on all users accounts and to be able to login without passwords.

Server side:

```
Meteor.methods( {
    "switchUser": function(user_id) {
        this.setUserId(user_id);
        return user_id;
    }
});
```

client side:

```
Meteor.call("switchUser",  user_id , function(error, idUser) {
    Meteor.connection.setUserId(idUser);
    Router.go('/profile');
});
```

It's working but is not persistent. After refresh or moving to another page ,the logged-in user is restored to the first (admin).

How can i swith user permanently with meteorjs ?

Comment: Thank you so much for this snippet, it helped a lot implementing "Switch User" in my app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it works but if you look on `local storage` you see that its set a login token `Meteor.loginToken` also among with user id `Meteor.userId`, maybe you have to set that too for the new user when you switch. Or you should consider making a method for login without password https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L107

Comment: Thank you , method for login without password seems the good way i will try